# Longest contiguous subsequence shared by every de Bruijn sequence of a given order?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, closed-form, upper-lower-bounds

For any given order $n$, find the length of the longest contiguous subsequence that occurs in every distinct binary [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of that order. We'll call that $L(n)$.

We define distinct de Bruijn sequences as those that differ regardless of reflection and [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Circular_permutations). For example, `00011101` and `00101110` would be considered the same sequence; thus for $n=3$, our answer would be $L(3)=8$, the length of that single distinct sequence. Likewise, we have the trivial cases $L(1)=2$ and $L(2)=4$, but that pattern won't keep up.

For larger $n$, we can still make progress. It's trivially true that $L(n) \geq n$, since every sequence of length $n$ must appear in $B(2,n)$ by definition.

We can slightly improve that naïve lower bound by observing that every sequence of order $n$ must contain $n$ ones in a row, padded by at least one zero on either side (since $n+1$ ones can never appear in an order-$n$ sequence). Therefore there exists a sequence of at least length $n+2$ which is common to every de Bruijn sequence of order $n$, so $L(n) \geq n+2$ for all $n>1$.

My guess is that that bound can be improved; I wouldn't be surprised if there's a simple closed-form expression for $L(n)$. If you can either find such a function, or alternatively give some reasoning as to why this question actually turns out to be difficult, I'll consider this answered.

Comment: The Wikipedia article says there are $2^{2^{n-1}-n}$ sequences.  This is such a large number that the minimal overlap has to be small.  I wonder if you can justify that the run of $n\ 1$'s is flanked by $00$ at one end and $01$ at the other, giving $n+4$

Comment: If I'm thinking it through correctly, that implies a worst-case upper bound (as $n \to \infty$) of $L(n)=2^{n-1}$, i.e. any common sequence must always be a hair less than half of the de Bruijn sequence. (Of course, I agree it probably turns out to be something more like your guess.)